# Core UI - Laravel -> Setting Up

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration, core-ui

I'm trying to make Core UI - Laravel work on my localhost (https://github.com/taboritis/coreui-laravel).

I have followed the steps. I can get to the login screen. I have created the John Doe user by running `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`, and I also made the migrations.

I've tried to log in, but every time, I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` =
>   john.doe@example.com limit 1)

My .env file looks like this:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=coreui
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

My config/database.php file looks like this:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'coreui'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

I'm kind of stuck here. What should I do next?

Comment: What is the `default` value set to in your `config/database.php` config file?

Comment: 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

Comment: The error shows that Laravel is trying to connect to MySQL using the username `homestead ` ... Have you removed the `DB_USERNAME=homestead` from the example `.env` [in the repository](https://github.com/taboritis/coreui-laravel/blob/master/.env.example)?

Comment: Yes I've replaced them in my .env the ones I've posted in my initial post but for some reason I can see is trying to use homestead@localhost credentials...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: For some reason I had to restart the web server and after several `php artisan config:clear` finally worked. Thanks everyone for your comments. You are all upvoted.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

The password is `321ewq` , as you can see in

```
coreui-laravel/database/seeds/UsersTableSeeder.php
```

[GitHub link of the user seeder](https://github.com/taboritis/coreui-laravel/blob/master/database/seeds/UsersTableSeeder.php)

**Edit**

The documentation suggests you to put this configuration in your .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=coreui
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

But your .env file looks like:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=coreui
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Restart a web server and run this command:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that also but still getting the same error as mentioned above.

Comment: The error shown has nothing to do with the example user's password.  It also shows the database username is not `root`, so is not coming from the `.env` file.

Comment: Even with the recommended config I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I have done a fresh installation, following the documentation, and everything work properly. In login page, I'm putting john.doe@example.com and 321ewq, It works fine with this credentials.

Comment: @MarianPop Try to restart a web server and run this command php artisan config:clear

Comment: Worked in the end. Thanks. I had to clear config for three times or so...